# Is it possible to recover from this un-soldering mistake?

Tags: pcb, soldering

I did a real mistake when un-soldering this PCB :

[image]

The metal part of the PCB was accidentally removed. Now it is impossible to solder anything at this place again: the solder material (what's the name again in english?) doesn't "glue" to the PCB anymore.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: This mistake is called 'lifting a pad/track/trace' and we have all done it at least once. Try searching 'soldering lifting a track' to find techniques for fixing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gently scrape a little of the soldermask (the green semitransparent paint) off the end of the track which leads to the pad you've lifted.
You should see bright shiny copper underneath where you've scraped. Make sure its reasonably clean, but don't be to hard on it or you'll destroy that too ...
Then push your wire through the hole with missing pad and bend it over to touch the clean copper at the end of the track.
Solder away ...

Comment: Should I do what you explain here : http://gget.it/293pu46q/2015-04-0813.54.47.jpg ?  Is there always copper under the green tracks ?  So every track can be scraped and under, there is solderable copper?

Comment: Last thing: with what would you scrape the green paint / soldermask?

Comment: yes, you should always find some copper somewhere underneath the soldermask, and yes that is the correct position to start scraping. I'd use a small sharp knife (xacto, scalpel, box-cutter, whatever....) Just *BE GENTLE*.

Comment: @Basj, yes scrap there.. I use an exacto knife for scrapping, but any thin sharp blade will work.  A razor blade in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is very unclear. As far as I understand, you mean to say that the copper track is removed from the PCB, probably due to overheating. If that's the case, the solder will not be able to stick to PCB as it only sticks to the copper layer. There are some ways to "FIX" ( make it run) depending on what you are trying to connect. A simple wire with one side soldered to component and the other side soldered to the copper TRACK instead of the copper END might just do it.

Comment: Yes, but impossible to solder one side of the wire to component: the component is under the "black glue" on the left the picture...